# Add columns to listview in C#

Tags: c#, listview, arraylist

I have in a SearchFlyClass an Arraylist GetFly()

```
        ...
        public ArrayList GetFly(int tip, string country)
        {
            ...
                    var list = new ArrayList();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        ...
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            decimal nr_zbor = reader.GetDecimal(cod_zbor);
                            string aeroport = reader.GetString(nume_aeroport);
                            string companie = reader.GetString(nume_companie);
                            list.Add(nr_zbor);
                            list.Add(companie);
                            list.Add(aeroport);
                        }
                    }
            ...
```

and I wish to put in Form1.cs the list in listview by columns[zbor(colZbor),airport(colAirport),company(colCompany)], but I don't now how

```
private SearchFlyClass searchFly = new SearchFlyClass();
private ArrayList fly = new ArrayList();
...
private void ShowResultFlySearch(int direction, string country)
        {
                fly = searchFly.GetFly(direction, country);
                for (int count = 0; count &lt; fly.Count; count++)
                {
                    string zbor = fly[0].ToString();
                    string companie = fly[1].ToString();
                    string aeroport = fly[2].ToString();
                    ListViewItem searchlist = new ListViewItem();
                    searchlist.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(elem));

                }
        }
```

can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to put ListView to View mode details, which you do with following code (it is also possible with setting View property in designer):

```
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.View = View.Details;
```

Then you have to assign columns to the listView (can also be done in designer):

```
listView.Columns.Add("zbor");
listView.Columns.Add("airport");
listView.Columns.Add("company");
```

After this you have to assign other columns to ListViewItem subitems, by modifying your function:

```
private void ShowResultFlySearch(int direction, string country)
{
    fly = searchFly.GetFly(direction, country);

    for (int count = 0; count &lt; fly.Count; count++)
    {
        string zbor = fly[0].ToString();
        string companie = fly[1].ToString();
        string aeroport = fly[2].ToString();

        ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem(zbor);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(airport);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(companie);

        listView.Items.Add (listViewItem);
    }
}
```

The function assumes that it is in Form1.cs and that you have listView variable instantized as class variable of type ListView. Basics of C# and object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues with this code. Firstly, is there any reason that you're using `ArrayList` instead of the generic collection types? E.g. `List<T>`

Secondly, I would create a type to store all of the related data for one instance of your entity, rather than putting the column values for the entity into an untyped collection.

Thirdly, your aren't referencing `count` anywhere in your `for` loop - presumably because the query is returning a single entity, and therefore the `for` loop is redundant because you know the number of items returned for a single entity. You are also using a variable `elem` which doesn't seem to have been defined.

**Updated**

Define a type that describes your entity:

```
public class Flight
{
   public decimal Code { get; set; }
   public string Company { get; set; }
   public string Airport { get; set; }       
}
```

Change your method to return an instance of your entity:

```
public Flight GetFlight(int tip, string country)
```

Create a new instance to return from the method and populate it from your database query result:

```
var flight = new Flight();
flight.Code = reader.GetDecimal(cod_zbor);
flight.Airport = reader.GetString(nume_aeroport);
flight.Company = reader.GetString(nume_companie);
return flight;
```

Now your other method can use the updated method:

```
var flight = searchFly.GetFlight(...);
// access flight properties here
```

This assumes that your query returns a single entity. If it returns a collection, then you can use `List<Flight>` or `IEnumerable<Flight>` as your return type as appropriate.

Comment: I now List<T> is bether, bat how can I add in the list using database I don't now give me an exaple please